# How to use an arbitrary type as a function argument?

Tags: function, rust, arguments

I am trying to write a generic function to pick up a random element in a vector of any kind. How can I specify an arbitrary vector type?

For example:

```rust
let list1: Vec<u32> = vec![1, 2, 3];
let list2: Vec<&str> = vec!["foo", "bar"];

fn print_a_random_element(a_list: Vec<?????>) {
    // do some stuff
}

print_a_random_element(list1); // get error
print_a_random_element(list2); // get error
```

Comment: You will be well-served to completely read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/). For example, [chapter 10](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-00-generics.html).

Comment: Yeap I know the book and I read it but rust is a complexe language and it's easy to forget some syntax rules. Anyway thanks for this reminder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic types specific to a function are declared using the `<>` syntax on the function definition:

```
fn print_a_random_element<T>(a_list: Vec<T>) {
    // do some stuff
}
```

See also:

- [Generic Types, Traits, and Lifetimes in *The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-00-generics.html)
- [Generic function to take struct as parameter in rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52129713/155423)
- [How to restrict generic implementation of a trait in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35525505/155423)
- [Is there any way to restrict a generic type to one of several types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40776020/155423)

Comment: Thx I tried that! but, what I didn't get was the <T> before the (a_list: Vec<T>) .